# Secure requests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, security, request

I have an application. My application has 3 layers.

- Front-end (contains front end design and functions)
- Back-end 1 (layer 2 - this is the back end server that get data form front-end layer and gives to back-end 2 that contains database operations. this layer is just a transporter)
- Back-end 3 is another back-end that triggers database operations by data that gets from layer 2.

When a XHR request send from front-end, it goes to layer 2, in layer 2 in Nodejs server, it will be add an API key and forward request to back-end 2 by special address. in back-end 2 it will check the API key first then trigger the operation.

Example:

```
1- form submited in front end to "/api/create_user"

2- in front-end 2 -> request handled "/api/create_user" get the request and 
   send to "/api/create_user_dkfjhierhgeirhuggridrfjkndf/APIKEY"

3- in back-end 2 -> it check the the request address and APIKEY then trigger 
   the request.
```

The problem is somebody has sent some request by an application they made out of my application.

**My question is**  how can I check requests in layer 2 and make sure this request has been came from  our front-end not out of our application?

Comment: "The problem is somebody has sent some request by an application they made out of my application." so they've built their own app based on yours? I'd say a unique key provided/required per form, and rate limits so people can't get the key too frequently.

Comment: My problem is I wanna recognize the requests is exactly from my front-end not out of my application.

Answer (score 1):

So... you have an API on the internet, and a web application that uses the API.

Somebody took a look at your application, figured out what your API calls are (reverse engineered), and they wrote their own front end.

If your application is a website, there are some things you can enforce. CORS is one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

With CORS, the web browser loads the webpage and sees a javascript xhr request. The web browser first ask the web server if the web page has permission to access the web server.

This relies on the web browser enforcing the access. If your adversary is using an app like curl, there isn't much you can do.

The most common mitigation is to require user registration and users need to login. Even this can be gamed, but now the adversary needs to duplicate your login flow, and grab the login credentials.

The final mitigation I'm aware of - You can continue to make it difficult for the adversary to get your pages. You can set a random cookie and verify that cookie for each request. You can set a secret code in the HTML, and pass that with your XHR request (like set it in a header) and verify it exists. You can change your API names, even make them randomly different every day. All these take time for the adversary to figure out, and until they figure it out, they are offline. If it's offline often enough, they might give up.